Let $z_1,z_2,z_3$ be any 3 complex numbers, such that $|z_1|=|z_2|=2, |z_3|=1$, $|\arg(\frac{z_1-z_3}{z_2-z_3})|=\frac{\pi}{2}$

Let $z_1,z_2,z_3$ be any three complex numbers, such that $|z_1|=|z_2|=2, |z_3|=1$ and $\left|\arg\left(\frac{z_1-z_3}{z_2-z_3}\right)\right|=\frac{\pi}{2}$. Then, the difference between the maximum and minimum values of $|z_1+z_2|$ is equal to

My Approach:
All I can think about is angle between vector $z_1-z_3$ and $z_2-z_3$ is $\frac{\pm\pi}{2}$
Then I tried to plot them on argand plane but can't think further.


Very rough sketch of solution. As others have pointed out, we can assume $z_3 = 1$ without loss of generality. Then $z_1, z_2$ are on the circle in the complex plane with radius $2$, such that the angle $z_1$-$z_3$-$z_2$ is a right angle. The value $\left| z_1+z_2 \right|$ is maximized when $z_1, z_2$ are at their closest, and minimized when they are at their furthest. The lines passing through $1$ with arguments $\pi/4$ and $-\pi/4$ intersect the radius-$2$ circle in the appropriate points. Geometry or algebra show that the desired difference is $2$.

@mathofile Your solution was posted as a picture, but one of the editors deleted it. Try editing your work - include what was in the picture.  Then your question will not be in danger of being deleted again.

For simplicity, I use same notation of points and their complex coordinates.
$z_1, z_2$ lie on a circle with radius $2,$  centered at $0.$
$z_3$ lies on the unit circle ${C}$ centered at $0,$ and on circle $C'$ with diameter $z_1z_2.$
WLOG, set $z_1=2.$
$|z_1+z_2|$ is a diagonal length of the rhombus with vertices $0, z_1, z_1+z_2, z_2.$ It is grey one in the picture.
$|z_1+z_2|$ is maximum if $z_1, z_2$ are as close as possible to each other, e.g. circles $C, C'$ touch externally in a single point $z_3.$
For minimum, I chose the labeling $w_1, w_2$ instead of $z_1, z_2.$
To better see the relation between lengths, set $w_1=z_2.$
$|w_1+w_2|$ is minimum if $w_1, w_2$ are as far apart as possible, and $C$ touches $C'$ internally.
The difference between the maximum and minimum is twice the radius of unit circle.
$$|z_1+z_2|-|w_1+w_2|=2$$


[+1] Good solution with geometrical insight. After correction, I still don't see how my own one (that I have cancelled) cannot give the result. Any idea ?

@JeanMarie I can't see your solution anymore. If you can, sent it to me please. But I only will be able to check it on Wednesday or later.

I have undeleted it. Thanks for having a look to it when you have time.

Adding to the correct answer being 2:
The minimum value for $|z_1+z_2|$ is about $$2\sqrt{2}\sqrt{1+\cos\left(4\left(0.997414\right)\right)}$$
which is about $1.64575362143$
The maximum value for $|z_1+z_2|$ is about $$2\sqrt{2}\sqrt{1+\cos\left(4\left(0.212016\right)\right)}$$
which is about $3.64575362143$
I'm getting these numbers from Wolfram1 and Wolfram2

WLOG, let $$(z_1,z_2,z_3)=(2e^{ix},2e^{iy},1)$$
Now, we have $$2e^{ix}-1=±ri(2e^{iy}-1)$$ for some real $r$
However, in order for $(z_1,z_2)$ to satisfy the condition that $|z_1+z_2|$ is extremized with respect to the constraint $\Re(\frac{z_1-1}{z_2-2})=0$, it turns out that $r$ must be $1$
(otherwise $|z_1+z_2|$ will fail to be extremized with respect to the constraint $\Re(\frac{z_1-1}{z_2-1})=0$)
$r=1$ gives us
$$\cos(x)±\sin(y)=\frac{1}{2}$$
and
$$\sin(x)∓\cos(y)=∓\frac{1}{2}$$
Hence my Wolfram calculations
As for the minimum and maximum values themselves, it takes only a little bit of trigonometry to demonstrate that $$|z_1+z_2|=|2e^{ix}+2e^{iy}|=2\sqrt{2+2\cos(x-y)}$$

Extra information
Since the system of equations implies that $x=2n\pi-y$, that means that ${z_1}/{z_3}$ and ${z_2}/{z_3}$ must be complex conjugates, whether we be in the minimum case or the maximum case.
Additionally, you can actually obtain exact figures for $z_1$ and $z_2$ in terms of $z_3$ in a) the minimum case and b) the maximum case.
In the minimum case for example, we have $$(z_1,z_2,z_3)=(2e^{±i\alpha}z_3,2e^{∓i\alpha}z_3,z_3)$$
where $\alpha=\arccos(\frac{1-\sqrt{7}}{4})$
In the maximum case, we have $$(z_1,z_2,z_3)=(2e^{±i\beta}z_3,2e^{∓i\beta}z_3,z_3)$$
where $\beta=\arccos(\frac{\sqrt{7}+1}{4})$
(and $z_3$ is of course some arbitrary number on the unit circle)

The exact value of the minimum is $\sqrt{7}-1$ and the exact value of the maximum is $\sqrt{7}+1$.
